# On using 'last' before past tense veb

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality

I want to say the last time I checked something was on [date].

> I last checked it on [date].

Is the above sentence using last correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. In *the last time*, it's an adjective. In *I last checked it*, it's an adverb.